# What does an exclamation mark next to an array mean when used in an if statement? "if (!used[i])"

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to understand my professor's code for teaching permutations, and I don't know what the "(!used[i])" inside an if statement means or does. Here's the full function, the if statement is within the for loop. Can anyone explain what it does?

```
void RecursivePermute(int n, int k, int* perm, int* used) {

 int i;

 // We've filled perm already. Print the corresponding permutation.
 if (k == n) {
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d ", perm[i]);
    printf("\n");
 }

 // Try each unused number in spot k.
 for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if (!used[i]) {           //this if statement is my question
        perm[k] = i;
        used[i] = 1;
        RecursivePermute(n, k+1, perm, used);
        used[i] = 0;
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Generally, the `!` stands for `not/false`... Unless it's css (`!important`):P

Comment: read : "if the content of the `i`-th index of the `edit` array is false (i.e. `==0`)"

Comment: -1: This is an elementary C language syntax question. The answer is already easily available.

Answer (score 3):

It means *not*, so will trigger the `if` statement when the `int` element `used[i] == 0`, so it could also be written as:

```
if (used[i] == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Better to write `(0 == used[i])` in order to catch the typo `(used[i] = 0)`. That is, avoid L-values on the left side of expressions where a typo in the operator can change the semantics without being cought by the compiler.

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham I disagree; I think Yoda Conditions are counter-intutitive, difficult to read and unnecessary these days.

Answer (score 1):

`used` is an array of integers. doing

```
if (!used[i])
```

checks if the current element is 0

what the recursive function do is each time print the array then put 1 in the next element, causing `perm`(and the output) to look like, depending on initiative k:

```
00000
01000
01200
01230
```

.
.
.

Answer (score 1):

Truth statements treat a variable as false if it's 0 or true if it's anything else.  ! is the not operator.  Therefore !used[i] will do the opposite, return true if used[i] is zero, or false otherwise.